# React ui-router test state change

Tags: reactjs, angular-ui-router, jestjs, enzyme

I need to write a test using Jest and enzyme that covers the basic implementation of react/ui-router in my application. All it needs to do is assert that a component is loaded in the DOM after a programatic state transition occurs.

I've been digging around in the docs and here on SO but can't find a way to accomplish this.

I have a simple state setup for a Home component

```
export const states = [
  { 
  url: '/home',
  name: 'home',
  component: Home,
  }
];
```

This is the test that I'm trying to accomplish:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Transition } from '@uirouter/react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { Home, Page } from './components/Layout';

describe('UIRouter', () => {
  it('go to home state', () => {
    Transition.router.stateService.go('home');

        const wrapper = mount(
           <UIRouter router={router} >
             <Page /> //component that contains <UIView />
           </UIRouter>\
         );
    expect(wrapper.find(<Home />).length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

When I try this code, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'stateService' of undefined
```

package.json:

```
@uirouter/react": "^0.8.0",
"react": "^16.3.2",
"react-dom": "^16.3.2",
"react-scripts": "1.1.4"
"enzyme": "^3.3.0",
```

Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `router` not `Transition`. Does this work?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Transition, UIRouterReact } from '@uirouter/react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { Home, Page } from './components/Layout';
import { states } from './states';

describe('UIRouter', () => {
  it('go to home state', () => {
    const router = new UIRouterReact();
    
    router.stateService.go('home');

        const wrapper = mount(
           <UIRouter router={router} states={states}>
             <Page /> //component that contains <UIView />
           </UIRouter>\
         );
    expect(wrapper.find(<Home />).length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```